# Checking the drive status using Smartctl

Tags: linux, smartctl

Can anyone help me identify my drive issue using the `smartctl` command?
When I execute `smartctl -h` the output contains "passed" but I still doubt the state of the disk.

Comment: No-one can help you identify a drive issue unless you provide the information

Comment: You mention that you have used `smartctl -h`. This is only some usage information. I'll assume it's a typo. Please edit your question with the real command you used. Also, as roaima mentioned: provide more info. Most important: the full output of the command.

Answer (score 0):

`smartctl -h` will only display the help page for smartctl

You can use the `--scan` option to scan for devices and `--scan-open` to scan for devices and try to open each device. I think what you were trying to do is getting health status with smartctl. In that case you need to use `smartctl -H` with **uppercase H** and not `smartctl -h`

To show the device SMART health status, try this

`smartctl -H /dev/sda`

or this

`smartctl --health /dev/sda`

You can also perform tests using
`smartctl -t /dev/sda` or `smartctl --test /dev/sda`